# Zookeeper znode for HBase tables

Tags: hbase

I am puzzled by the zookeeper entries for HBase-1.2.1 tables. I see the following information zookeeper

**hbase:meta table**

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] get /hbase/table/hbase:meta
�master:600009�HvP�L�PBUF
cZxid = 0x720095ea53
ctime = Thu Jun 02 18:49:58 UTC 2016
mZxid = 0x720095ea54
mtime = Thu Jun 02 18:49:58 UTC 2016
pZxid = 0x720095ea53
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 1
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 31
numChildren = 0
```

**wordcount table**

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 4] get /hbase/table/wordcount
�master:60000K~��   #PBUF
cZxid = 0x72009a358d
ctime = Thu Jun 09 17:58:10 UTC 2016
mZxid = 0x72009a3597
mtime = Thu Jun 09 17:58:11 UTC 2016
pZxid = 0x72009a358d
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 2
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 31
numChildren = 0
```

If I understand correctly, `/hbase/table/wordcount` stores the location of the RegionServer that contains the data. However, I am surprised to see `master:600009`. I am completely clueless as what `master:600009` refers to. Could someone help me understand?

Comment: only the hbase:meta table znode contains the location of the region server where meta is hosted. all the other tables znodes are to keep track of "the state" of the table (enabled, disabled, in transition, ...)

Comment: But notice the content of znodes I pasted in my post. I dont find location of the region server anywhere. I only see master:600009. Regionservers reside in a node called hbase-rs1.colo